# How does changing economy (currency value) affect travel package?

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, transportation

How do changes in economy affect travel prices of flights ?

Comment: I don't see what's opinion-based about this. The question is not about predicting whether the rupee will get stronger or anything like that but about the effect of such a change on travel. Knowledge of the travel industry and basic economics should enable someone to provide a comprehensive and objective answer.